# woocommerce modify final price based on quantity

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently setting up a WooCommerce shop.
Basically this is what I am trying to achieve

"If you place an order for a certain quantity of a product for example 40 pieces from product "A" and then you add another 90 pieces of product "B" then you have ordered a total of 130 pieces (quantity in cart is equal to 130)

So now my prices are based on how many pieces you ordered in total not per piece.

So if you order any quantities between 80 & 150 then all you have to pay is a flat price of $50 (so if you order 91 or 101 or 150 your final cost will be $50).

So this is just an example as I would like to setup other pricing brackets.

Any idea how can that be achieved, I tried multiple plugins recommended by WooCommerce but non of them do what I am looking for.

Your help is greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

At it's simplest, this code will do what you're asking:

```
function custom_price_function( $total, $cart ) {
    if( $cart->cart_contents_count <= 150 && $cart->cart_contents_count >= 80 )
        $total = 50;
    return $total;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'custom_price_function', 10, 2 );
```

You add it to your theme `functions.php` file or custom plugin code. It hooks into a filter in the WooCommerce file `class-wc-cart.php` in the carts class `calculate_totals()` function. This filter is at line 1361 at time of writing.

If you take a look at the function you'll see other properties that may be useful for calculating the total price the way you want it. For example taxes are contained in the `$this->tax_total` variable accessed in the `custom_price_function()` with `$cart->tax_total`.

Comment: This is amazing,, the code works, but I need to apply the price structure before any taxes applied or or discounts or shipping,, so I guess the adjustment of the price needs to be done on the subtotal not the final total,,, I looked at the class-wc-cart.php file and I can't see anything that sets the price for the sub total,, am I looking in the wrong place... thanks alot by the way

Comment: forgot to mention :  I also have price based on country plugin installed,, so these prices need to have exchange rate applied to theme...

Comment: @user1830684 Geez talk about moving the goal posts. There is another filter called 'woocommerce_get_price' in the function `get_price()` that you could hook into to change the base price. There, you could calculate the base price as 50/cart_contents_count. To get that variable you'll have to instantiate a cart object from within that filter function.

Comment: can you please contact me, maybe I can outsource this for you to do? are you interested?

Comment: @user1830684 Yes I'm interested. I can't find contact details on your profile but there are details on mine. Go to www.phoenixwebdev.com.au, My contacts are in the footer.

Comment: Sure, I am going to drop you an email soon